# Python Flask POST 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: python, linux, http, post, flask

I'm trying to POST data to a website using flask, when I try to return the data I get a 400 Bad Request error.

Here is my python code that sends the POST request:

```
import requests
from random import randint

def Temp():
return randint(0,20)


data = {'windspeed':WindSpeed(), 'Temp': Temp(), 'WindDir':WindDir()}
r = requests.post('http://10.0.0.119', data = data)
print (r.text)
```

And this is the server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    Temp = data['Temp']
    return render_template('main.html', name=Temp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

This returns a 400 error when run in a a browser, but the client script gets the correct respone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Temperature</h1>
<p>15</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Where 15 is the data['Temp'] variable.

Comment: Your client fails the same as when posting with a browser. The problem is that `get_json()` expects the data to be in JSON format, but using a normal post will send form encoded data. Use `json=` instead of `data=` or `data=json.dumps(data)`. Or, better, in your server simply use the data as a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just navigating to `http://10.0.0.119` then you're sending a GET request to `def result()` which will result in a bad request because there is no `data['Temp']`

In order to make this work in a browser you will need to send a POST request from the app itself, and then have a way to view it.

**Your app could be:**

```
import requests
from random import randint

from flask import Flask, request, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

def Temp():
  return randint(0,20)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.get('data')
        Temp = data['Temp']
        return render_template('dispaly_data.html', name=Temp)
    else:
        data = {'Temp': Temp()}
        return render_template('post_data.html', data=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

**And your form in `post_data.html` could be something like:**

```
<form action="/" method='post'>
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="{{ data }}"/>
    <input type='submit' value='Send Post'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You send wrong request. You have to use `json=data` to send it as JSON

```
r = requests.post('http://10.0.0.119', json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting JSON in your client and nor is your browser, so don't try to process it as JSON in your server. Just access the values using `request.form` for POST requests or `request.args` for GET requests:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
    else:
        data = request.args

    temp = data.get('Temp')
    return render_template('main.html', name=temp)
```